# Vagrant + ZF2: vagrant not able to bring up ZF2 interface

Tags: zend-framework2, vagrant, puppet

I installed a unix environment using vagrant vb and Puphpet Provision. After vagrant up, when i navigate to my host address in the browser, i am able to load the server page. However, after i installed zf2 skeleton and did a composer.phar update, and navigate to the host address again, it should display the zend framework welcome page but it displayed :

```
<?php
/**
 * This makes our life easier when dealing with paths. Everything is relative
 * to the application root now.
 */
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));

// Decline static file requests back to the PHP built-in webserver
if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server' && is_file(__DIR__ . parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH))) {
    return false;
}

// Setup autoloading
require 'init_autoloader.php';

// Run the application!
Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php')->run();
```

Anyone know why my vagrant does not process the php file as it should be?

Comment: Problem is that your www server (apache or nginx) isn't properly configured to work with PHP. It's not related to vagrant or puppet. You have to check out how to set puppet provisioning to configure php properly in www server.

Comment: hello @max any feedback did you resolve your issue im in same situation if so please share it could help. Thank you

Comment: Hello @Marcel, yes i resolved the issue, did you generated a new config.yml from puphpet.com recently? do you mind to post your config.yml?

Comment: thanks sure here link to my config.yml gist https://gist.github.com/mdjaman/faf6b46e81863621d429

Comment: Replied on your issue in gist. Please check